# How to get different Received: from headers from each domain using Postfix Virtual Domain Hosting?

Tags: centos, email, postfix

We have try to configure Postfix for multiple domain with dedicated IPS. When I am sending mail from different domain webmail then header show same local or main domain name. For all domains:

```
Received: from control.yourdomain.com (ns1.domain.com. [1xx.2xx.2xx.xx1])
```

I have tested different `main.cf` and `master.cf` but the do not work. If anyone knows how to configure `main.cf` and `master.cf` for multiple domains and dedicated IPS, then help me.

I want result like this. Example:

1. I am sending mail from `domain2.com` webmail then the header for all domains looks like this:

   ```
   Received: from domain2.com (domain2.com. [1xx.2xx.2xx.xx2])
   ```
2. I am sending mail from `domain3.com` webmail then the header for all domains looks like this:

   ```
   Received: from domain3.com (domain3.com. [1xx.2xx.2xx.xx3]) on all domain.
   ```

Server OS CentOS 6.3, configured all domain with dedicated IPS.

Comment: Is it a few domains? (less than 10)  Which web server and web scripting language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% secure, but I saw an installation like this some months ago.

Set up the transports:

Example, `/etc/postfix/transport`:

```
client.com   :client1
client.pl    :client2
```

Then the `master.cf`:

```
client1  unix -       -       n       -       -       smtp
   -o smtp_bind_address=10.5.5.1
   -o smtp_helo_name=client.com
   -o syslog_name=postfix-client1

client2  unix -       -       n       -       -       smtp
   -o smtp_bind_address=10.5.5.2
   -o smtp_helo_name=client.pl
   -o syslog_name=postfix-client2
```

And configure all your devices (firewalls, etc..) to listen to this IP like it is mentioned on [postfix.org](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_bind_address)

Here you have another question like yours but is for use [random transports at postfix](https://serverfault.com/a/436703/126219)