# Stop Postfix sending mail from localhost

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

When my mailserver sends mail here are the headers:

```
Received: from example.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by example.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id EB14D48159
    for <oli@myemaildomain.com>; Thu, 26 Dec 2013 11:56:12 +0000 (GMT)
```

This usually really isn't an issue apart from one customer's Postini filter is being particularly violent and seems to class this as an illegal address. I could fight them but it seems like it would be easier to just send email from the legal IP, right..?

So I've been through practically every Postfix setting. I have already set the following variables to `example.com`: `masquerade_domains`, `smtp_helo_name`, `myhostname`, `myorigin`, and I've set `smtp_bind_address` to our external IP. I don't know what else I can change that might have an effect.

How can I change the address/IP to our external address/IP?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, Postfix 2.9.6. I have seen and tried (as noted above) answers like those on [How to make Postfix use another IP address?](https://serverfault.com/questions/92181/how-to-make-postfix-use-another-ip-address) and I don't have *any* bind addresses in my master.cf file (I think that was the old way of doing things?)

Comment: What is sending the mail?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's a Django website but I'd like it to be system wide.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Hampton got me wondering if the client had something to do with this. Django by default uses `localhost` as the email host.

I added this to my `settings.py`

```
EMAIL_HOST = "example.com"
```

And BOOM. Right domain, right IP. Emails aren't blocked.

Answer (score 0):

### sending email with sendmail - django

Have you considered sending email using sendmail program/ (look alike) provided by postfix?

StackOverflow question below provides link to django snipet:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450748/sending-email-with-sendmail-django
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1864/

It starts one process per one message.