# Sending email with postfix on a specific IP address fails. Error 81126 with Gmail

Tags: linux, email, postfix, ip

Recently, I started to receive errors from Gmail:

> host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.110.27] said:
> 550-5.7.25 [X.X.X.X] The IP address sending this message does not have
> a 550-5.7.25 PTR record setup, or the corresponding forward DNS entry does
> not 550-5.7.25 point to the sending IP. As a policy, Gmail does not accept
> messages 550-5.7.25 from IPs with missing PTR records. For more
> information, go to 550-5.7.25
> https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#ip-practices  550-5.7.25 To
> learn more about Gmail's sender policy, go to 550 5.7.25
> https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126.
> r9-20020a0560001b8900b0033b09244271si4920918wru.914 - gsmtp (in reply to
> end of DATA command)

I looked at this and realise that my mail server running on IP Y.Y.Y.Y was actually sending email from the IP Address X.X.X.X. My server has two public facing IP addresses. One - Y.Y.Y.Y - is the one configured with the PTR record and reverse dns and A record. X.X.X.X is used for unrelated services.

Now the PTR record and the reverse DNS is all set correctly. What I want to know is why is postfix choosing to send most of the emails out on IP X.X.X.X when it really should send out on Y.Y.Y.Y? This would solve the error that Gmail is reporting.

I've seen this previous question - [How to make Postfix use another IP address?](https://serverfault.com/questions/92181/how-to-make-postfix-use-another-ip-address) - and I've set the bind address as it states but this does not appear to fix the problem. Postfix certainly *listens* on this IP but it doesn't appear to affect the address the emails are sent from.

This box sends email for various virtual domains, not just the domain assigned to the box. For example, the box itself has domain name abc.com and emails such as alice@abc.com get sent out fine. However, the mail server also sends out mail for bob@def.com. These emails are goin out over IP Address X.X.X.X which causes all the trouble. I suspect postfix is deciding this must be the correct ip for def.com for some reason.

I'm trying to get postfix to always send out on the Y.Y.Y.Y ip. I've looked into sender_dependent_default_transport_maps for different options for the different domains. This seems not to work either.

Here is my master.cf

```
smtp    unix    -   -   n   -   -   smtpd
   -o smtp_bind_address=Y.Y.Y.Y
   -o myhostname=mail.abc.com

Y.Y.Y.Y:smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
   -o smtp_bind_address=Y.Y.Y.Y
   -o myhostname=mail.abc.com

domain3   unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
   -o smtp_bind_address=Y.Y.Y.Y
   -o smtp_helo_name=mail.abc.com

submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtp_bind_address=Y.Y.Y.Y
  -o smtp_helo_name=abc.com
  -o myhostname=abc.com

pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache

spamassassin   unix   -     n       n      -       -       pipe
       user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}

dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
       flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -u spamd -e /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}

policy-spf unix    -       n       n       -       0     spawn
      user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/policyd-spf
```

domain3 is setup in /etc/postfix/sender_transport

```
@def.com domain3:
```

and in the main.cf we have this:

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport
```

For some reason, emails sent from alice@abc.com are fine - it chooses the correct ip Y.Y.Y.Y. This ip address also happens to match the A record for the box. The second IP X.X.X.X is used for other, unrelated services, so why is postfix insisting on choosing X.X.X.X for sending emails with any domain that isn't abc.com? I'm clearly missing something important here around virtual mailboxes and aliases perhaps? I should note everything was running great until this second public IP was added.

I've tried setting the smtp bind addresses as well

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_bind_address

```
smtp_bind_address = Y.Y.Y.Y
inet_interfaces = all
```

I've tried setting inet_interfaces to various setting, all to no avail.

How can I force postfix to send email on Y.Y.Y.Y and only that IP address, regardless.
Thanks all! :)

Comment: I think you missed the message... a PTR record has nothing to do with Postfix, and there are 73k hints for searching on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Error+81126+with+Gmail) and debugging email issues with DNS related issues.

Comment: No, that's not the case at all. The PTR record is set and correct and points to Y.Y.Y.Y. Postfix *should* be sending out on this IP and was before a second IP was added to this machine. My question is *why is postfix choosing one IP - X.X.X.X - instead of Y.Y.Y.Y when every setting in postfix related to this (as far as I know) is Y.Y.Y.Y

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Postfix use another IP address?](https://serverfault.com/questions/92181/how-to-make-postfix-use-another-ip-address)

Comment: Thanks :) I had read that previously and I thought I'd give it a go - smtp_bind_address is set to Y.Y.Y.Y and inet_interfaces = all but this has not worked. I can confirm with netstat that it is at least *listening* on the right IP but still not sending correctly.

Comment: then please unhide the domain, MX issues will be easier to verify

Comment: Then try playing with inet_interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the issue. Turns out that yes, a single ip address in smtp_bind_address and inet_interfaces field does indeed work.

The problem was an incorrect iptables rule set by the wireguard interface, also on that box, using the X.X.X.X ip. With that removed postfix sends out on the correct IP.

Thanks for comments :)